# Test cases can be synchronized in HP ALM 11.5 using Synchronizer .How is it possible?

Tags: hp-alm

We need to consolidate Test cases across all projects.We have an idea of using Synchronizer.I am totally new to it. Currently we are using ALM 11.5 version.

So how to synchronize test cases from one projects to another.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would appear to be a matter for HP ALM support

Comment: have you got an error or a scenario that you expect to work but isnt?  I think it could fall under the remit of the board as it involves the setup/usage of a testing tool but i think we need a good deal more information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the documentation the Synchronizer does not support syncing of test cases, but only defect data between projects.

From the [HP ALM Synchronizer user guide](http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc110/sync/almsynchronizer/HP-ALM-Sync-UserGuide.pdf):

> Welcome to HP ALM Synchronizer. Synchronizer enables you to
>   synchronize HP Application Lifecycle Management (ALM) data with data
>   in another application. You can: ➤ Synchronize defect data between ALM
>   and Rational ClearQuest or Microsoft Team Foundation Server. ➤
>   Synchronize requirement data between ALM and Rational RequisitePro or
>   Microsoft Team Foundation Server. ➤ **Synchronize defect data between
>   two ALM projects**.

Maybe contact HP ALM support to ask if this possible an how. I think the HP ALM community here is to small to have experience with this sync product.